# Add back un-loaded folder in ASP.Net project

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am working on a ASP.Net project and I unloaded a folder "Reports" that had subfolders and RDLC files in it. The folder I un-loaded is from this path:

"C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\Project1\changerapp\Content\reports"

The folder Reports has some sub folders and RDLC files. Now I want to load the Reports folder like the same way it was before. But when I select "Add existing item" , it is not letting me add the folder (with all its contents). Rather it is making me select files inside that Reports folder. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out in 2 minutes after posting the question.

So we have to click the "Show all files" icon on top and select the folder we want to add back. Right click the folder and select "Include in the project" and the folder will be included.